# Compressing map algebra outputs from ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0, spatial-analyst, map-algebra

When creating a raster map algebra output, is it possible to set its compression?

I'm creating a model which generates many hundreds of rasters, and currently each is being stored without any compression which quickly adds up. I expected to be able to use `arcpy.env.compression` but that seems to have no effect. Example script which produces this behavior:

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.compression = 'LZW' # supported by GeoTIFF and most packages

map = Raster("raster.tif") + 100
map.save("raster_plus_100.tif") # would expect this output to have compresssion
```

Comment: Does it have anything to do with LZW being proprietary? I have used this reference for my decision-making in regard to image format... http://arcpadteam.blogspot.com/2006/08/raster-tips-1-choosing-raster-format.html

Comment: Maybe with this added... http://packages.python.org/lzw/lzw-module.html

Comment: The patents on LZW expired about 7 years back, but I can't get it to work with other compression methods either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the problem is that arcpy.env settings only apply to tools. Calling a method on an object is not technically a "tool". In a practical sense, the arcpy.env settings should apply to stuff like Raster.save() but it doesn't appear to work that way.

I was able to save a raster *with compression* by using arcpy.CopyRaster_management(). Something like this:

```
arcpy.env.compression = 'LZW'
t1 = arcpy.Raster('sample.tif') + 100
arcpy.CopyRaster_management(t1, 't1.tif')
del t1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using [ApplyEnvironment](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/ApplyEnvironment/005m000000q6000000/) on the raster variable.

```
#convert raster form meter to feet
raster = arcpy.Raster(raster_path) * 0.3048
arcpy.env.compression = 'LZW'
compressedRaster = arcpy.sa.ApplyEnvironment(raster)
compressedRaster.save(output_path)
```

Comment: Hi James, thanks for the tip. I couldn't seem to get it to work with GeoTIFF files, but perhaps I missed a step.